# How do I map a nested collection, Map<Key,List<Values>>, with hibernate JPA annotations?

Tags: java, hibernate, collections, jpa, annotations

I have a class I am not sure how to annotate properly.

My goal for Holder::data:

- List should maintain order not by comparator but by the natural ordering of the elements in the array. (Which can be an ndx column if that is helpful.)
- Holder will have the only reference to data, so Cascade all is probably applicable as well.

I am also open to a different design that removes the map, if that would make for a cleaner design.

```
@Entity
public class Holder extends DomainObject {
  private Map<Enum,List<Element>> data;
}

@Entity
public class Element extends DomainObject {
  private long valueId;
  private int otherData;
}

@Mappedsuperclass
public class DomainObject {
 // provides id
 // optimistic locking
 // create and update date
}
```

Comment: "such that its list is ordered based upon the arrangement in the list", can you rephrase?

Answer (score 10):

I don't think it is possible with hibernate(-core) to map any collection of collections:

> Collections may contain almost any
> other Hibernate type, including all
> basic types, custom types, components,
> and of course, references to other
> entities.

(from [the official doc](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/collections.html#collections-persistent))

Notice the **almost** and the omission of the collection type.

A workaround: You need to introduce a new type 'in between' the collection holder and the element. This type you can map as an entity or a component and it refers the original content of the map, in this case a list.

Something like:

```
@Entity
public class Holder extends DomainObject {
  @OneToMany
  private Map<Enum,InBetween> inBetweens;
}

@Entity
public class InBetween extends DomainObject {
  @OneToMany
  private List<Element> elements;
}

@Entity
public class Element extends DomainObject {
  private long valueId;
  private int otherData;
}

@Mappedsuperclass
public class DomainObject {
 // provides id
 // optimistic locking
 // create and update date
}
```

The rest of the mapping depends on your particular situation, but is rather straightforward.

Comment: Link is dead, working link: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/collections.html

Answer (score 3):

Here is a blog about collection of collections in hibernate https://xebia.com/blog/mapping-multimaps-with-hibernate/

Hope it will help. It helped me.

Regards,
Anton

Answer (score -1):

Please note that the referred link to the Hibernate documentation seems out of date, I found the following working: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.5/reference/en/html/collections.html