# How to map a 2-d matrix in Java to Hibernate/JPA?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, multidimensional-array

I have a legacy database I'm trying to redesign into the 21st century.  One of the existing data structures involves a particular class which contains a 2-dimensional matrix of values.  If I were to reverse-engineer this class from the database, I'd end up with a series of attributes like:

```
private BigDecimal NODE_1_MATRIX_POS_1_1;
private BigDecimal NODE_1_MATRIX_POS_1_2;
```

and so on.  Since this is a 6x6 matrix, there are a lot of such columns.

I've been looking for a better way, but I'm not sure I'm there.  What I'd like to do is something like this:

```
@Entity
public class TestClass {

    @Id
    private long id;

    @CollectionOfElements
    @JoinTable(
        name="MATRIX_DATA", 
        joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="ENTRY_ID"))
    private List<List<BigDecimal>> matrix;
```

But this fails:

```
org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: java.util.List, at table: MATRIX_DATA, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(element)]
```

Rather than just trying to fix the error, I thought I'd ask around and try to find the right *approach* to solving this mapping challenge.  Has anyone found success and satisfaction mapping multidimensional arrays via JPA?

Comment: I'm not sure of the best approach here but I think to work round your error you would need to create your own UserType

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Rather than just trying to fix the error, I thought I'd ask around and try to find the right approach to solving this mapping challenge. Has anyone found success and satisfaction mapping multidimensional arrays via JPA?

AFAIK, nested collections are not supported by standard JPA. The JPA wiki book has a good section on this topic (I'm quoting only a part of it):

> #### [Nested Collections, Maps and Matrices](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Relationships#Nested_Collections.2C_Maps_and_Matrices)
>
> It is somewhat common in an object
>   model to have complex collection
>   relationships such as a `List` of
>   `List`s (i.e. a matrix), or a `Map` of
>   `Map`s, or a `Map` of `List`s, and so
>   on. Unfortunately these types of
>   collections map very poorly to a
>   relational database.
>
> **JPA does not support nested collection relationships, and normally
>   it is best to change your object model
>   to avoid them to make persistence and
>   querying easier. One solution is to
>   create an object that wraps the nested
>   collection.**
>
> For example if an `Employee` had a
>   `Map` of `Project`s keyed by a
>   `String` project-type and the value a
>   `List` or `Project`s. To map this a
>   new `ProjectType` class could be
>   created to store the project-type and
>   a `OneToMany` to `Project`.
>
> ...

And that would be my suggestion. For example:

```
@Entity
public class TestClass {    
    @Id
    private long id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="testClass")
    private List<MatrixRow> matrix;
}
```

Where `MatrixLine` would be (omitting many details):

```
@Entity
public class MatrixRow {
    @Id
    private long id;

    @ManyToOne
    private TestClass testClass;

    @CollectionOfElements
    private List<BigDecimal> row;
}
```

Or **maybe** you could use a custom user type (I'm not too sure how this would work).

Or (after all, you're already using non portable annotations) have a look at this question to see how you could extend Hibernate:

- [How do I map a nested collection, `Map<Key,List<Values>>`, with hibernate JPA annotations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/939235/how-do-i-map-a-nested-collection-mapkey-listvalues-with-hibernate-jpa-annot/948591#948591)

Comment: That's exactly the kind of thing I was attempting to construct late yesterday.  I'll give it a go this morning, incorporating the differences from your example.  Thanks, Pascal!

Answer (score 5):

### Hibernate Types project

You can map a PostgreSQL multidimensional array using the [Hibernate Types](https://github.com/vladmihalcea/hibernate-types) project.

You can choose to use a Java array on the entity attribute side or use `List`.

### Database table

For exmaple, assuming you have the following `plane` database table:

```
CREATE TABLE plane (
    id INT8 NOT NULL,
    name VARCHAR(255),
    seat_grid seat_status[][],
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

Where the `seat_status` is a PostgreSQL enum:

```
CREATE TYPE seat_status
AS ENUM (
    'UNRESERVED',
    'RESERVED',
    'BLOCKED'
);
```

### JPA entity

You can map the `seatGrid` column using the [`EnumArrayType`](https://vladmihalcea.com/multidimensional-array-jpa-hibernate/):

```
@Entity(name = "Plane")
@Table(name = "plane")
@TypeDef(
    name = "seat_status_array",
    typeClass = EnumArrayType.class
)
public static class Plane {
 
    @Id
    private Long id;
 
    private String name;
 
    @Type(
        type = "seat_status_array",
        parameters = @org.hibernate.annotations.Parameter(
            name = "sql_array_type",
            value = "seat_status"
        )
    )
    @Column(
        name = "seat_grid",
        columnDefinition = "seat_status[][]"
    )
    private SeatStatus[][] seatGrid;
 
    //Getters and setters omitted for brevity

    public SeatStatus getSeatStatus(int row, char letter) {
        return seatGrid[row - 1][letter - 65];
    }
}
```

So, you need to declare the appropriate Hibernate Type to use. For enums, you need to use the `EnumArrayType`:

```
@TypeDef(
    name = "seat_status_array",
    typeClass = EnumArrayType.class
)
```

The `@Type` annotation allows you to pass parameters to the Hibernate Type, like the SQL array class:

```
@Type(
    type = "seat_status_array",
    parameters = @org.hibernate.annotations.Parameter(
        name = "sql_array_type",
        value = "seat_status"
    )
)
```

### Testing time

Now, when you persist the following `Post` entity:

```
entityManager.persist(
    new Plane()
        .setId(1L)
        .setName("ATR-42")
        .setSeatGrid(
            new SeatStatus[][] {
                {
                    SeatStatus.BLOCKED, SeatStatus.BLOCKED,
                    SeatStatus.BLOCKED, SeatStatus.BLOCKED
                },
                {
                    SeatStatus.UNRESERVED, SeatStatus.UNRESERVED,
                    SeatStatus.RESERVED, SeatStatus.UNRESERVED
                },
                {
                    SeatStatus.RESERVED, SeatStatus.RESERVED,
                    SeatStatus.RESERVED, SeatStatus.RESERVED
                }
            }
        )
);
```

Hibernate will issue the proper SQL INSERT statement:

```
INSERT INTO plane (
    name,
    seat_grid,
    id
)
VALUES (
    'ATR-42',
    {
        {"BLOCKED", "BLOCKED", "BLOCKED", "BLOCKED"},
        {"UNRESERVED", "UNRESERVED", "RESERVED", "UNRESERVED"},
        {"RESERVED", "RESERVED", "RESERVED", "RESERVED"}
    },
    1
)
```

And, when fetching the entity, everything works as expected:

```
Plane plane = entityManager.find(Plane.class, 1L);

assertEquals("ATR-42", plane.getName());
assertEquals(SeatStatus.BLOCKED, plane.getSeatStatus(1, 'A'));
assertEquals(SeatStatus.BLOCKED, plane.getSeatStatus(1, 'B'));
assertEquals(SeatStatus.BLOCKED, plane.getSeatStatus(1, 'C'));
assertEquals(SeatStatus.BLOCKED, plane.getSeatStatus(1, 'D'));
assertEquals(SeatStatus.UNRESERVED, plane.getSeatStatus(2, 'A'));
assertEquals(SeatStatus.UNRESERVED, plane.getSeatStatus(2, 'B'));
assertEquals(SeatStatus.RESERVED, plane.getSeatStatus(2, 'C'));
assertEquals(SeatStatus.UNRESERVED, plane.getSeatStatus(2, 'D'));
```

Comment: Adding a new (and better) answer for a 10-year old question! Is there a badge for that? :-)

Comment: That's the Persistence badge 

Comment: To me this looks like a typo.... Did you mean PersistentBag?

Comment: This only works with Postgress as a DB? What would be a good solution for other db' s that don't support (multidimensional) arrays of objects.

Comment: Not many DBs support arrays. For those, the workaround is to use JSON instead. In a JSON object, you can emulate nested arrays.