# Is it possible to persist a map containing another collection

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, collections

I wonder if it is possible to have the following data structure in a jpa managed entity.

```
@Entity
public MyEntity {

    @ElementCollection
    public Map<String, Set<MyEntityTwo>> map;
}
```

I did some basic tests but come up with the following error:

```
JPA error
A JPA error occurred (Unable to build EntityManagerFactory): Could not determine type for: java.util.Set, at table: ModelOne_map, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(map)]

play.exceptions.JPAException: Unable to build EntityManagerFactory
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4099237/how-to-map-a-2-d-matrix-in-java-to-hibernate-jpa) which states that it is not possible with standard JPA and that the prefered way is to create a wrapper object.