# How to ignore quotes for nested ARRAY in a PostgreSQL query in a Spring Data @Query

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

The question may seems stupid but I am stuck on executing that kind of query:

```
UPDATE user SET productArr = ARRAY[ARRAY[2,2],ARRAY[3,2],ARRAY[1,3]] WHERE id = 1;
```

within a `@Query` Spring Data.

I defined my repository method like:

```
    @Modifying
    @Query(value = """
            UPDATE user
            SET productArr = :productArr WHERE id = :userId
            """, nativeQuery = true)
    void updateProductArr (@Param("productArr") String productArr, @Param("userId") Long userId);
```

I set `String productArr="ARRAY[ARRAY[2,2],ARRAY[3,2],ARRAY[1,3]]"`
The error is:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column "productArr" is of type text[] but expression is of type text
```

I tried to change the type of `productArr` from String to `String[]` or `List<String>` without success.

I also tried this solution: `UPDATE user SET productArr = REPLACE(:productArr,'"','') WHERE id = :userId` but same result.

Please note that when I run that query on a database console it works well.
Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you update your data using this query:

```
UPDATE user SET productArr = ARRAY[ARRAY[2,2],ARRAY[3,2],ARRAY[1,3]] WHERE id = 1;
```

Postgres automatically converts you integer array to string array, because as I understand the `productArr` field is type of `text[]`

You can filter this field using this correct SQL queries:

```
select * from users
where productArr = ARRAY[ARRAY['2','2'],ARRAY['3','2'],ARRAY['1','3']]
```

or

```
select * from users
where productArr = '{{2,2},{3,2},{1,3}}'::text[]
```

In your spring project you have two ways do this.

1. Use array type for input parameters, don't use string type
2. You can use string type for input parameters, but then you should cast type inside the native query.

For example:

```
@Modifying
@Query(value = """
        UPDATE user
        SET productArr = (:productArr)::text[] WHERE id = :userId
        """, nativeQuery = true)
void updateProductArr (@Param("productArr") String productArr, @Param("userId") Long userId);
```

And use:

```
String productArr = "{{2,2},{3,2},{1,3}}"
```

Comment: I went for the 2nd proposition which seems more readable. What is the best type to use for that strange type in an entity if I want to avoid nativeQuery? A String, or a String[] or List<String>, or a List<String[]>?

Comment: Usually used list<list<String>> or String[][]. For detail information how to map a 2d arrays in Java Hibernate visit this url. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4099237/how-to-map-a-2-d-matrix-in-java-to-hibernate-jpa - Maybe help you.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is brought on by a type mismatch between the PostgreSQL array type and the `productArr` argument of your Spring Data query. To fix this, modify the type of the `productArr` parameter in your method signature to `String[]` and explicitly define the parameter type using the `::text[]` cast in your query. This guarantees for the update query to run effectively.