# how to store a Map<String, List<String>> using JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, dictionary

I am trying to store a `Map<String, List<String>>`; using JPA.

My entity looks like:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Profiles_table")
public class Profiles {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "profile_ID", updatable = false, nullable = false)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;

    private final HashMap<String, List<String>> AllProfiles;
    ...
}
```

I have tried a lot of settings for the map but its not working...

The last one I tried:

```
@ElementCollection
@MapKeyColumn(name = "Profil")
@Column(name = "Permissions")
@CollectionTable(name = "Profiles_permissions", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "profile_ID"))
```

The following exception is thrown:

```
org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Illegal attempt to map a non collection as a
@OneToMany, @ManyToMany or @CollectionOfElements: [...]Profiles.AllProfiles
```

thanks in advance

Comment: Take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/939235/how-do-i-map-a-nested-collection-mapkey-listvalues-with-hibernate-jpa-anno It seems there is no proper way to do this. You will have to use a custom class, I'm afraid.

Comment: thanks for that, I missed it when I search! I'll have a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really an answer but this is the way I've done it.

I store the second level of collection as a blob.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Profiles_table")
public class Profiles {

@Id
@Column(name = "profile_ID", updatable = false, nullable = false)
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private int                                 id;

@Column(length = 16777210)
private final HashMap<String, Set<String>>  AllProfiles;
```

Answer (score 1):

Strings are not entities, so you shouldn't use @OneToMany, etc...

Did you try this:

```
@CollectionOfElements
private Map<String, List<String>> allProfiles;
```

Comment: that wont works with error Could not determine type for: java.util.List, at table: ......

Comment: Pretty sure this answer meant `@ElementCollection`, which fails with the same error @Nawa mentions.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried declaring AllProfiles as an interface type (let's say Map)?
Check ["Illegal attempt to map a non collection as a @OneToMany, @ManyToMany or @CollectionOfElements" in hibernate when annotating a ConcurrentHashMap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8169196/illegal-attempt-to-map-a-non-collection-as-a-onetomany-manytomany-or-collec)

Comment: using interface type for allprofile throws this (as hibernate is bad with interfaces): Could not determine type for: java.util.Map, at table: profiles_table, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(all_profiles)