# Hibernate JPA mapping having a map which value is a list

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, enums, hashmap

I'm looking how to map in JPA a hashmap with its value being a list.

I've 2 entities:

```
EntityA {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  private Integer id;

  @MapKey(name = "nature")
  @MapKeyEnumerated(EnumType.STRING)
  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "entityA", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  private Map<NatureEnum, List<EntityB>> mapEntityB = new HashMap<NatureEnum, List<EntityB>>();     
}


EntityB {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  private Integer id;

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "ID_ENTITYA", nullable = false)
  private EntityA entityA;

  @Column(name = "NATURE", nullable = false)
  @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
  private NatureEnum nature;
}
```

You will have guessed that of course the map doesn't work as it's missing something telling it it's not just one EntityB in it.

The rest does work and if i change the map by a regular List it works fine.
So how can i manage to "group by" my EntityB in one list depending on the value of Nature?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Found this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/939235/how-do-i-map-a-nested-collection-mapkey-listvalues-with-hibernate-jpa-anno so it seems it's not possible without creating a entity in between ...

Comment: That's right, JPA does not support nested collections. You need to change your model. See: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Relationships#Nested_Collections.2C_Maps_and_Matrices

Comment: Wrap `List<EntityB>` into a new entity in order to have `Map<NatureEnum, EntityW> mapEntityW`, and put your list into `EntityW`. **EDIT**: @gadget's comment shows you exactly how to do this.

Comment: Thanks guys. Wonder if there is anyway to mark this as solved when the answers are in comments? Regards.

Comment: Thank you for the Wiki @gadget! And about other guys, thank you as well! Hope you have a great coding time!

Comment: @TheBakker - Which of the comment did really Help you? I am trying to have `Map<String, Set<String>` in my Entity. or even `Map<String, List<String>` can be also fine if possible?