# Mapping nested collections with hibernate JPA annotations? Map<Key,Set<Values>>

Tags: spring, jpa, collections, annotations, kotlin

I'm not sure how to annotate the bellow classes correctly. What I'm trying to do is to have on the **User** entity, a list of roles for a mapped **Asset**.

```
@Entity
class Asset{
    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    var id: Long = -1
}

@Entity
class Role {
    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    var id: Long = -1
}

@Entity
class User{
    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    var id: Long = -1

    ???
    var roles: Map<Asset, Set<Role>> = HashMap()
}
```

From what I discovered hibernate does not support a map of sets ([link here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/939235/how-do-i-map-a-nested-collection-mapkey-listvalues-with-hibernate-jpa-anno)). So I tried other options as an intermediate class like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/941069).

But I'm struggling with the annotations. Can someone please tell what annotations I have to put on the three classes?

If someone knows a better approach instead of the map, to have the user roles by asset, please tell.

Comment: As far as I understand, a JPA entity design has to be able to be converted to an [ERD](https://www.smartdraw.com/entity-relationship-diagram/). The `Map<K, Collection<V>>` object is hardly achievable in an ERD. How did you design you data in your database? You might need to create an `AssetRoles` entity and have a `@OneToMany Collection<AssetRoles>` in your `User` entity. Unrelated to JPA but where the syntax `var xxx: ` comes from?

Comment: Ups it's kotlin, I'm updating the tags. I'm open to the database design (it's done by annotations) but what makes sense to me was a user_role_asset table with user_id, role_id and asset_id. I was trying to use something like you said Collection<AssetRole> but I'm struggling with the annotation. I can't seem to get it working.

Comment: I would use OneToMany and ManyToOne annotations. 1 Asset to many Roles and 1 User to Many Assets.

Comment: @Ursache can you provide some sample please?